# meaning of aprapta parpako vidhi

Tags: purva-mimamsa

I came across the following assertion in an online text- "Aprapta parpako Vidhi". Translated into English, it means, "A Vidhi is that which puts one in a position which ordinarily one is not apt to get into"

I can't understand 'parpako' Is it a misprint? What is the text from which this maxim is taken? Any ideas?